# Mapa de cloropetas clasificado por Natural Breaks de Jenks en R

Tags: r, rstudio, color, mapa

Tengo los siguientes paquetes cargados y lo que busco es crear un mapa de cloropetas clasificado por los Natural Breaks de Jenks para una variable en específico, "desplaz_pond_minu".

```
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(tidyverse)
require(classInt) 

#Lo primero es encontrar los valores clasificados por Natural breaks
desplaz_pond_minu.nat= classIntervals(bdd_sf_Final$desplaz_pond_minu, n = 6, style = 'jenks')$brks

#Con ello crearemos una nueva columna en la bdd que tenga los valores clasificados por Natural breaks
bdd_sf_Final$desplaz_pond_minu.nat = cut(bdd_sf_Final$desplaz_pond_minu, breaks=desplaz_pond_minu, include.lowest = TRUE)
```

Luego uso ggplot para graficar:

```
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = bdd_sf_Final, aes(fill = desplaz_pond_minu.nat))
```

El resultado es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, tengo dos preguntas respecto a esto:

1.¿Cómo puedo cambiar la escala de colores para que sea continua?

2.¿Existe una forma más sencilla de hacer mapas de cloropetas con clasificación de Jenks? Tengo algo más de 300 variables como "desplaz_pond_minu" y creo que sería muy tedioso repetir el proceso del ejemplo para cada una.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Escala continua

Lo que buscas no es exactamente una escala continua, por que los datos no lo son, sino más bien una escala gradual. Hay muchas formas de resolverlo, pero básicamente o usas alguna paleta ya definida por ejemplo:

```
library("viridis")

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = bdd_sf_Final, aes(fill = desplaz_pond_minu.nat)) + 
  scale_fill_viridis(option = "inferno", discrete=TRUE)
```

O también alguna de las funciones básicas de ggplot para generar el rango de colores:

```
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red", na.value = NA)
```

Revisa la [documentación](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html).

#### Automatizar clasificación

Entiendo que lo que quieres es clasificar un conjunto grande de variables y no tener que hacerlo una a una. Lo que se puede hacer es encapsular la clasificación en una función:

```
get_range <- function(x, n) {
  i = classIntervals(x, n = n, style = 'jenks')$brks
  cut(x, breaks = i, include.lowest = TRUE)
}
```

Y simplemente la invocamos dentro de un ciclo implícito, por ejemplo usando algunas columnas de `mtcars`:

```
df <- mtcars[,c(1,4)]

l <- lapply(df, get_range, 3)
```

Esto nos retornará una lista dónde cada elemento es un factor con los niveles de la clasificación, si queremos integrarlo al mismo `data.frame`:

```
new_df <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, l)
new_df <- setNames(new_df, paste0(colnames(new_df),".nat"))
cbind.data.frame(df, new_df)

                     mpg  hp     mpg.nat    hp.nat
Mazda RX4           21.0 110 (17.3,24.4]  [52,123]
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0 110 (17.3,24.4]  [52,123]
Datsun 710          22.8  93 (17.3,24.4]  [52,123]
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4 110 (17.3,24.4]  [52,123]
Hornet Sportabout   18.7 175 (17.3,24.4] (123,215]
Valiant             18.1 105 (17.3,24.4]  [52,123]
Duster 360          14.3 245 [10.4,17.3] (215,335]
Merc 240D           24.4  62 (17.3,24.4]  [52,123]
Merc 230            22.8  95 (17.3,24.4]  [52,123]
Merc 280            19.2 123 (17.3,24.4]  [52,123]
Merc 280C           17.8 123 (17.3,24.4]  [52,123]
Merc 450SE          16.4 180 [10.4,17.3] (123,215]
Merc 450SL          17.3 180 [10.4,17.3] (123,215]
Merc 450SLC         15.2 180 [10.4,17.3] (123,215]
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4 205 [10.4,17.3] (123,215]
Lincoln Continental 10.4 215 [10.4,17.3] (123,215]
Chrysler Imperial   14.7 230 [10.4,17.3] (215,335]
Fiat 128            32.4  66 (24.4,33.9]  [52,123]
Honda Civic         30.4  52 (24.4,33.9]  [52,123]
Toyota Corolla      33.9  65 (24.4,33.9]  [52,123]
Toyota Corona       21.5  97 (17.3,24.4]  [52,123]
Dodge Challenger    15.5 150 [10.4,17.3] (123,215]
AMC Javelin         15.2 150 [10.4,17.3] (123,215]
Camaro Z28          13.3 245 [10.4,17.3] (215,335]
Pontiac Firebird    19.2 175 (17.3,24.4] (123,215]
Fiat X1-9           27.3  66 (24.4,33.9]  [52,123]
Porsche 914-2       26.0  91 (24.4,33.9]  [52,123]
Lotus Europa        30.4 113 (24.4,33.9]  [52,123]
Ford Pantera L      15.8 264 [10.4,17.3] (215,335]
Ferrari Dino        19.7 175 (17.3,24.4] (123,215]
Maserati Bora       15.0 335 [10.4,17.3] (215,335]
Volvo 142E          21.4 109 (17.3,24.4]  [52,123]
```

En este ejemplo hemos clasificado  dos columnas con 3 niveles, sin embargo, imagino que en tu caso no todas las columna tiene la misma cantidad de estos. Mi sugerencia es que armes grupos por la cantidad de niveles que tengas, y ejecutas el código tantas veces por cada conjunto de columnas.

Comment: Patricio, cuando pruebo con la escala de viridis me aparece el siguiente mensaje: `> ggplot() + 
+   geom_sf(data = bdd_sf_Final, aes(fill = desplaz_pond_minu.nat)) + 
+   scale_fill_viridis(option = "inferno", direction = -1)
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` Luego, cuando intento automatizar la clasificación: `> get_range <- function(x, n) {
+   i = classIntervals(x, n = n, style = 'jenks')$brks
+   cut(x, breaks = i, include.lowest = TRUE)
+ }
> l <- lapply(bdd_sf_Final, get_range, 3)
Error in classIntervals(x, n = n, style = "jenks") : var is categorical`

Comment: Efectivamente tienes datos categoricos, usa `viridis` indicando esto, así: `scale_fill_viridis(option = "inferno", discrete=TRUE)`. El otro error, seguramente se debe a que alguna variable tal vez no sea numérica o sea un factor, no puedo saberlo sin ver los datos. Selecciona en principio, solo unas pocas columnas numéricas en el `lapply` para confirmar esto. Saludos.